# how to get next month date between two dates and when month is same get next date in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
**startdate = '2022-1-1'
enddate =  '2022-9-15'

expected output =2022-2-1
                 2022-3-1 
                 2022-4-1
                 2022-5-1
                 2022-6-1
                 2022-7-1
                 2022-8-1
                 2022-9-1
                 2022-9-2
                 2022-9-3
                 2022-9-4
                 2022-9-5
                 2022-9-6
                 2022-9-7
                 2022-9-8
                 2022-9-9
                 2022-9-10
                 2022-9-11
                 2022-9-12
                 2022-9-13
                 2022-9-14
```

**

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime
start_Date = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
endDate = datetime(2022, 9, 15)
tdelta = relativedelta(months=+1)

while start_Date <= endDate:
      print(start_Date)
      start_Date += tdelta
```

I'm able to get all the next month date within two date but not sure how to increment the date when they are in the same month within the same loop.
**output of the above code
2022-2-1
2022-3-1
2022-4-1
2022-5-1
2022-6-1
2022-7-1
2022-8-1
**

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

start_Date = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
endDate = datetime(2022, 9, 15)

while start_Date < endDate - relativedelta(days=1):
    if start_Date.month < endDate.month:
        start_Date += relativedelta(months=1)
    else:
        start_Date += relativedelta(days=1)
    print(start_Date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

```
2022-02-01
2022-03-01
2022-04-01
2022-05-01
2022-06-01
2022-07-01
2022-08-01
2022-09-01
2022-09-02
2022-09-03
2022-09-04
2022-09-05
2022-09-06
2022-09-07
2022-09-08
2022-09-09
2022-09-10
2022-09-11
2022-09-12
2022-09-13
2022-09-14
```